# Network change event in Oracle MAF?

Tags: oracle-maf, oracle-adf-mobile

How can I detect network change event in Oracle MAF for that if I want to set/reset a variable value as network state changes?

Note: I know that how can we detect network change event using Cordova with `settimeout()` and I don't want to use `settimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply for displaying the information it should be enough to bind a UI component to the device data control. For actively doing something you would need to do it manually using the DeviceManagerFactory --> DeviceManager and then use a thread to poll the information

Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was looking for if this was possible without using thread.